# Swing drawString() with color set to white draws in black

Tags: java, swing, kde-plasma

Have anyone any idea why? Could it be because of my inverse white-on-black KDE theme? If so, how can I draw string in exactly specified color?

P.S. while making the screenshot, once I saw that the text was correctly in white! But only once. WTF?

P.P.S. seems that text is drawn in black on first paint event, after that, other repaints draw in white as they should. Why?

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ColorTest extends JComponent {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add((new ColorTest()));
        frame.setSize(240, 320);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.drawString("WHITE", 50, 40);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("BLACK", 50, 80);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawString("RED", 50, 120);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString("GREEN", 50, 160);
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawString("BLUE", 50, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: Odd. It works fine for me (tested multiple times).

Comment: It have to be related to my kubuntu/kde/theme/etc.. but I don't know where to start the search...

Comment: Don't forget to call `super.paintComponent(g);`

Comment: Also, don't forget to initialize the UI on *Event Dispatch Thread*, see [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for details.

Comment: Unfortunately, the issue reproduces when `super.paintComponent(g)` is called and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` is used. But the code with the issue is not so simple, it's pretty complex with tons of interfaces and inheritences. I cannot reproduce it with the simple piece of code and trying to locate the place where it occures.

Comment: Is it a feature of the window system to invert otherwise invisible text?